# Samba shared subdirectories report as files

Tags: network-shares, samba, redirection, cifs

I just upgraded my home server to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials.
My ancient living room media player makes a lot of assumptions about SMB shares that are incompatible with the new server.

My preferred solution is to host a small Ubuntu VM that mounts the media share on the Windows server, and re-serves it using legacy NetBIOS & SMB in workgroup mode.

I've got this line in /etc/fstab (with standins to anonymize)

```
//$SERVERNAME/Media /mnt/media cifs credentials=/home/$USER/.smbcredentials,uid=1000 0 0
```

This is my /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[Media]
path = /mnt/media
available = yes
only guest = yes
read only = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
```

This almost works. I can browse to it from either my Windows 7 clients, or my media player. However, the subdirectories are being reported as files, not directories.

```
C:\>net use q: \\MediaHost\media
C:\>q:
C:\>dir

 Volume in drive Q is Media
 Volume Serial Number is 13A5-E058

 Directory of Q:\

01/25/2014  12:47 PM    <DIR>          .
01/26/2014  03:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/18/2014  03:18 PM                 0 Directory1
01/13/2014  06:50 PM                 0 Directory2
...
```

What is causing the directories to get remapped as files, and how can I fix it?

I've confirmed that on the Ubuntu host, the subdirectories are reported as `drwx...`, so it would appear the directory-ness is being lost in the resharing, not the mounting.

**Edit:** After some more research, it appears this is a documented bug:

[ServerFault Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/491464/directories-shown-as-files-when-sharing-a-mounted-cifs-drive)

[Samba Bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9346)